# I need to recursively remove duplicates from a string in Java, using this method as my Professor told me

Tags: java

I can't visualise what removeDups(s.substring(1, s.length())); would put on the stack so I can't figure out what to put in the conditional. Code below, any help would be great thanks

```
public String removeDups(String s){
    if (s.length() < 1) return s;
    char c0 = s.charAt(0);
    String r = removeDups(s.substring(1, s.length()));
    if (c0 == r.charAt(0)){
        return; // not sure what to put
    else{
        return; // not sure here either
    } 
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like whatever you fill in the blanks with, you will end up getting an index out of bounds exception on `if (c0 == r.charAt(0))`

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine what `removeDups` is supposed to do--it will remove all duplicates within a string. So the string `r` represents the string from the second character onwards, but without duplicates. So now what you are left with is `c0`, the first character of the string, and `r`, the string from the second character onwards with only unique characters. How do you check if this string has any duplicates? I'll leave you to figure out that part for yourself :)

As a side note, this is the great thing about recursion--as long as you handle base cases correctly and use the correct logic for the recursive steps, you can make safe assumptions that make coding easier!

Comment: Thanks heaps! Got an A